# Wait the end of a css3 transition in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, gridster

Im actually using the gridster.js jquery module and i have an issue with the CSS3 transition.

I put some content in my 'li' tags and when the page load, i adapt the widget size to the content (to avoid text-overflow).

If i keep the original gridster css, my while loop which look at the width & height of widgets goes infinite..

Is there a way to avoid this?? (it work perfectly when i remove just the transition effect in the css file).

Here is a part of the function that i use for set a correct height on my block (to avoid overflow)

```
while($('li')[i].scrollHeight-8>$('li').eq(i).height())
    {
        if($('li')[i].scrollHeight-8>$('li').eq(i).height()){
           gridster.resize_widget($('li').eq(i), parseInt($('li').eq(i).attr('data-sizex')), parseInt($('li').eq(i).attr('data-sizey'))++);
        }
    }
```

When i use this function with the transitions removed on the css, it work, if i put the transition again, the while become infinite.